# PowerShell Find all variables of the type Forms.Panel

Tags: variables, powershell, types

In the process of creating a .NET form in PowerShell, I stumbled upon an annoyance. I need to be able to deactivate the visibility of all panels except for the one that has to be displayed. To do this it seems convenient to search for all available variables of the type `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` and put their status to `$Panelx.Visible = $False`.

**Example of all kinds of variables:**

```
[String]$Stuff = 'Blabla'
$Panel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$Panel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$Panel3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$TabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
```

This gives me the correct results, but I can't set the `Visible` status to `$False`

```
Get-Variable | ? {$_.Value} | ? {(($_.Value).GetType().Name) -eq 'Panel'} | % {
    $_.Visible = $false
}
```

How is it possible to only list the variables of the type panel and then put them on `$Panel.Visible = $False`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that Get-Variable returns objects of type PSVariable, so the Panel object is defined within. Use the member property `value` to retrieve it, like this:

```
Get-Variable |where {$_.Value -is [System.Windows.Forms.Panel] } | % {$_.value.visible = $false}
```

Comment: Awesome Micky, works great! Thank you :) Another silly question: why is that `-eq` does't work and `-is` does?

Comment: `-eq` is the Equal operator, so it basically checks that a value equals another value (i.e 1 equals 1 or "abc" equals "abc"). `-is` is the 'is of type' operator, so it's better suited to verify the type of variables versus another. Types can have different names, ie `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` or just `Panel`, so using `-eq` is dangerous. However no matter the name of the type, if you use `-is` it will find it. It would have worked with `-eq` like this: `Get-Variable |where {$_.Value.GetType().name -eq 'Panel' } 
`

Comment: Slight edit about my comment above. In fact `$_.value` could be $null, and so it would have needed to be checked when using `-eq` instead of `-is`: `Get-Variable |where {$_.Value -ne $null -and $_.Value.GetType().name -eq 'Panel' } | % {$_.value.visible = $false} 
`